# I got stuck migrating a small JavaScript project to Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a little project that uses pure HTML, CSS and JavaScript only. And as I’m getting into the world of Vue I decided it would be a good idea to try to migrate it to Vue.js.

Here it is working in JavaScript:

```js
const toKelvin = {
  Celsius: (t) => t + 273.15,
  Farenheit: (t) => (t + 459.67) / 1.8,
  Rankine: (t) => t / 1.8,
  Rømer: (t) => ((t - 7.5) * 40) / 21 + 273.15,
  Newton: (t) => (t * 100) / 33 + 273.15,
  Delisle: (t) => 373.15 - (t * 2) / 3,
  Reaumur: (t) => t * 1.25 + 273.15,
  Kelvin: (t) => t
};

decimalTemp.addEventListener("input", decimalTempEvent);
temperatureList.addEventListener("input", temperatureEvent);
decimalTempEvent();

function decimalTempEvent() {
  const step = 1 / 10 ** decimalTemp.value;
  celsiusIn.step = step;
  kelvinIn.step = step;
  farenheitIn.step = step;
  rankineIn.step = step;
  romerIn.step = step;
  newtonIn.step = step;
  delisleIn.step = step;
  reaumurIn.step = step;
  temperatureEvent();
}

function temperatureEvent({
  target = kelvinIn
} = {}) {
  const round = (val) => val.toFixed(decimalTemp.value);
  const kelvin = Math.max(
    0,
    toKelvin[target.dataset.units](Number(target.value))
  );

  celsiusIn.value = round(kelvin - 273.15);
  kelvinIn.value = round(kelvin);
  farenheitIn.value = round(kelvin * 1.8 - 459.67);
  rankineIn.value = round(kelvin * 1.8);
  romerIn.value = round(((kelvin - 273.15) * 21) / 40 + 7.5);
  newtonIn.value = round(((kelvin - 273.15) * 33) / 100);
  delisleIn.value = round(((373.15 - kelvin) * 3) / 2);
  reaumurIn.value = round((kelvin - 273.15) * 0.8);
}
```

```html
<h3>Temperature</h3>
<input class="decimals" type="number" min="0" max="10" value="0" step="1" id="decimalTemp">
<label for="decimalTemp">Decimals</label>

<dl id="temperatureList" class="blocks">
  <dd>
    <input id="celsiusIn" type="number" data-units="Celsius">
    <label for="celsiusIn">Celsius (ºC)</label>
  </dd>
  <dd>
    <input id="kelvinIn" type="number" min="0" value="293" step="1" data-units="Kelvin">
    <label for="kelvinIn">Kelvin (K)</label>
  </dd>
  <dd>
    <input id="farenheitIn" type="number" data-units="Farenheit">
    <label for="farenheitIn">Farenheit (ºF)</label>
  </dd>
  <dd>
    <input id="rankineIn" type="number" data-units="Rankine">
    <label for="rankineIn">Rankine (ºRa)</label>
  </dd>
  <dd>
    <input id="romerIn" type="number" data-units="Rømer">
    <label for="romerIn">Rømer (ºRø)</label>
  </dd>
  <dd>
    <input id="newtonIn" type="number" data-units="Newton">
    <label for="newtonIn">Newton (ºN)</label>
  </dd>
  <dd>
    <input id="delisleIn" type="number" data-units="Delisle">
    <label for="delisleIn">Delisle (ºDe)</label>
  </dd>
  <dd>
    <input id="reaumurIn" type="number" data-units="Reaumur">
    <label for="reaumurIn">Reaumur (ºRé)</label>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

Initially, when trying to migrate to Vue, I had some doubt about whether functions should be placed in methods or in watch.

I put the `eventListener` call in the HTML and used `@input`, but I don’t know if it would be correct to use `@change`.

Well, here’s the mess:

```
<template>
    <div id="temperatureList" @input="temperatureEvent">
        <label for="decimalTemp">Decimal Places </label>
        <input class="decimals" type="number" min="0" max="10" value="0" step="1" @input="decimalTempEvent" id="decimalTemp" />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input id="kelvinIn" type="number" min="0" step="1" v-model="Kelvin" /></td>
                <td>Kelvin (K)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input id="celsiusIn" type="number" v-model="Celsius" /></td>
                <td><label for="celsiusIn">Celsius (ºC)</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input id="farenheitIn" type="number" v-model="Fahrenheit" /></td>
                <td><label for="farenheitIn">Farenheit (ºF)</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input id="newtonIn" type="number" v-model="Newton" /></td>
                <td><label for="newtonIn">Newton (ºN)</label></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "Temperature",
    data() {
        return {
            Kelvin: 293.15,
            Celsius: 20,
            Fahrenheit: 68,
            Newton: 7,
            decimalTemp: 0,
        };
    },
    watch: {
        toKelvin: {
            Celsius: (t) => t + 273.15,
            Farenheit: (t) => (t + 459.67) / 1.8,
            Newton: (t) => (t * 100) / 33 + 273.15,
            Kelvin: (t) => t,
        },

    decimalTempEvent() {
            const step = 1 / 10 ** decimalTemp.value;
            celsiusIn.step = step;
            kelvinIn.step = step;
            farenheitIn.step = step;
            newtonIn.step = step;
            temperatureEvent();
        },

    temperatureEvent({ target = kelvinIn } = {}) {
            const round = (val) => val.toFixed(decimalTemp.value);
            const kelvin = Math.max(0, toKelvin[target.dataset.units](Number(target.value)));

            celsiusIn.value = round(kelvin - 273.15);
            kelvinIn.value = round(kelvin);
            farenheitIn.value = round(kelvin * 1.8 - 459.67);
            newtonIn.value = round(((kelvin - 273.15) * 33) / 100);
        },
    },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
table {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
table tr td {
    text-align: left;
}
input {
    text-align: right;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace `watch` and `data` with `computed` (it's basically `data` + `watch` in one). `computed` by default has only getter, but you can add setter to it also.

I've also optimise your code a bit. Overall you need only base unit (let's assume `Kelvin` will be the one), then operate on this and change other units based on it while any other is being changed.

Working code ([snippet on codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-kilby-96zf1?file=/src/App.vue)):

```
<template>
  <div id="temperatureList">
    <label for="decimalTemp">Decimal Places </label>
    <input
      class="decimals"
      type="number"
      min="0"
      max="10"
      step="1"
      v-model="decimalTemp"
    />
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input
            id="kelvinIn"
            type="number"
            min="0"
            step="1"
            v-model="Kelvin"
          />
        </td>
        <td>Kelvin (K)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input id="celsiusIn" type="number" v-model="Celsius" /></td>
        <td><label for="celsiusIn">Celsius (ºC)</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input id="farenheitIn" type="number" v-model="Fahrenheit" /></td>
        <td><label for="farenheitIn">Farenheit (ºF)</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input id="newtonIn" type="number" v-model="Newton" /></td>
        <td><label for="newtonIn">Newton (ºN)</label></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Temperature",
  data: () => ({
    decimalTemp: 0,
    baseInKelvins: 293.15,
  }),
  computed: {
    Kelvin: {
      get: function () {
        return this.baseInKelvins.toFixed(this.decimalTemp);
      },
      set: function (newVal) {
        this.baseInKelvins = +newVal;
      },
    },
    Celsius: {
      get: function () {
        return this.fromKelvin()
          .Celsius(this.baseInKelvins)
          .toFixed(this.decimalTemp);
      },
      set: function (newVal) {
        this.baseInKelvins = this.toKelvin().Celsius(+newVal);
      },
    },
    Fahrenheit: {
      get: function () {
        return this.fromKelvin()
          .Fahrenheit(this.baseInKelvins)
          .toFixed(this.decimalTemp);
      },
      set: function (newVal) {
        this.baseInKelvins = this.toKelvin().Fahrenheit(+newVal);
      },
    },
    Newton: {
      get: function () {
        return this.fromKelvin()
          .Newton(this.baseInKelvins)
          .toFixed(this.decimalTemp);
      },
      set: function (newVal) {
        this.baseInKelvins = this.toKelvin().Newton(+newVal);
      },
    },
  },
  methods: {
    fromKelvin: () => ({
      Celsius: (t) => t - 273.15,
      Fahrenheit: (t) => 1.8 * t - 459.67,
      Newton: (t) => ((t - 273.15) * 33) / 100
    }),
    toKelvin: () => ({
      Celsius: (t) => t + 273.15,
      Fahrenheit: (t) => (t + 459.67) / 1.8,
      Newton: (t) => (t * 100) / 33 + 273.15
    }),
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
table tr td {
  text-align: left;
}
input {
  text-align: right;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I was able to understand, in fact, the use of `computed`. The solution you used for `fromKelvin` and `toKelvin` was brilliant, thank you very much for that.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with future coding in Vue :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question wasn't very clear from your post, so i'll just try to address the issues and doubts you wrote about.

> I had some doubt about whether functions should be placed in methods
> or in watch.

Functions that are invoked from the template should be placed inside the methods property, as opposed to computed which does not accept parameters and is expected to only return a "computed" value.

Watch is a property meant to hold the functions that "listen" for changes (in props, route params etc...), that way they will trigger each time the props or params change.

> I put the eventListener call in the html and used @input, but I don’t
> know if it would be correct to use @change.

The difference between @input and @change is that @input triggers with each key press, but @change triggers with each submit (or pressing enter if not inside of a form and there's no submit button linked to that input).

So it really comes down to expected outcome, performance, and taste.

If your'e not fetching a lot of data from an API when the input value (that is linked via v-model) changes, then i would probably go with @input, and even if you are fetching a lot of data, i would use a "debounce" method to only fetch the data after a certain delay to avoid over-fetching.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It will definitely help me to write some functions better.